# SQL Stored Procedure Update statement

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

What is other way of writing this query??

```
Update TempTableDisplay         
SET  _cPayment = case When exists(
                   select Tofield from #UFTFMappingTempTable where ToField='Payment') 
                   then IsNull(S.Payment,0) 
                else dbo.fnGetMaximum((ISNULL(M.NetTaxDue0,0) + ISNULL(M.NetTaxDue1,0) + ISNULL(M.NetTaxDue2,0) + ISNULL(M.NetTaxDue3,0) + ISNULL(M.NetTaxDue4,0) + ISNULL(M.NetTaxDue5,0) + ISNULL(M.NetTaxDue6,0)),0)
                end
```

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: I don't understand your question: why do you want to write it another way?

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way:

```
if exists(select Tofield from #UFTFMappingTempTable where ToField='Payment') 
begin
    Update TempTableDisplay         
    SET  _cPayment = IsNull(S.Payment,0) 
end
else
begin
    Update TempTableDisplay
    set _cPayment = dbo.fnGetMaximum((ISNULL(M.NetTaxDue0,0) + ISNULL(M.NetTaxDue1,0) + ISNULL(M.NetTaxDue2,0) + ISNULL(M.NetTaxDue3,0) + ISNULL(M.NetTaxDue4,0) + ISNULL(M.NetTaxDue5,0) + ISNULL(M.NetTaxDue6,0)),0)
end
```

But as you've probably noticed, you've omitted a lot of the query - e.g. which tables do 'S' or 'M' refer to? Without that info, none of this is going to work.